# I am looking for a logic to print the currency

Tags: python, list

```
fund = [["$3.3M"], ["£ 4.5Million"],["€900000"],["£ 720000"],["CAD  4.5Million"],["$5.7M"],["£ 7.8 Million"],["CAD $ 9.5Million"]]

for i in fund:
    n=i[0]
    if "$" in n:
        print("usd")
    elif "£" in n:
        print("Pound")
    elif "€" in n:
        print("Euro")
    elif "CAD $" in n:
        print("cad")
```

Output:

```
usd
Pound
Euro
Pound
usd
Pound
usd
```

here Canadian dollars have been identified as USD because the "$" symbol is present, how can I rectify this issue?

Comment: You likely want to use a library to do this instead of writing your own code. Also, why can't you just use an `and` and a `not` statement?

Comment: Move `if "CAD $" in n:` above `if "$" in n:`. In that case when canadian dollars come up, the first statement will be triggered and it will bever get to USD.

Comment: Check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. You might want to change it to something like, "How can I check if a string contains a substring or a different substring that contains the first substring?" though that's not very succinct.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a condition that preempts another, you can simply put the other one first:

```
if "CAD $" in n:  # <- moved here
    print("cad")
elif "$" in n:
    print("usd")
elif "£" in n:
    print("Pound")
elif "€" in n:
    print("Euro")
```

Output:

```
usd
Pound
Euro
Pound
usd
Pound
cad
```

Comment: For an explanation, the program initially sees the dollar sign and prints out USD instead of CAD. The CAD $ if statement is never triggered because the first if statement was already executed. | If you removed the else from the elif statements, it would print both CAD and USD.